# javascript tags for link on image with timeout 3 secs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to put a link on the image using JavaScript tags with a timeout function of 3 secs,

The js code

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://test.com/cdb/smail_images/TVSmilesLogo.jpg';
img.onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://test.com/';
};
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

and html file code is

```
<script src="t.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want the image to show after 3 seconds or the click to not work until after 3 seconds or a delay when clicking?

Comment: can you please elaborate, your question isn't clear

Comment: Trying to go beyond the raw interpretation of your question, I would assume what you are really looking to do is to make the image clickable when it is loaded, cant really make sense out of this timeout otherwise. ```img.onload = function(){
img.onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://test.com/';
};
};```

Comment: If you assign an onload handler you need to set the src AFTER assigning

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout` function to solve it:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   alert("do something");
},3000);//3000 means msec
```

Comment: Worked well ,Satisfied

Answer (score 0):

all you need is wrap your redirect into `setTimeout()` function. also I suggest to change mouse cursor via css, so user will know the image is clickable

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/350/350/';
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.onclick = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://test.com/';
  }, 3000);
};
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  }

img {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

img:hover{
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think he wants to delay the clickability? Also now it will look clickable for 3 seconds before being clickable

Comment: @mplungjan yep, I left that up to asker, but okay, I've edited a bit) reg delay for clickability - that is how I understood his question which is not clear

Comment: Hi , Thanks for all your help, I can get the link on the image but the page is not redirecting automatically after 3 secs.Can you pls Let me know how to make this and can you pls tell me how to mention width and height of the image.

Comment: Worked well ,Satisfied

Comment: @MadhanKumar hey, finally I've got your request. now it will redirect to the page in 3 seconds after the click. if that helps please mark the answer as accepted